# Any way to get previous Google Scholar results format?

Tags: google-scholar

On Friday or thereabouts, [Google Scholar changed its results format](https://scholar.googleblog.com/2017/09/better-ways-of-getting-around.html) and now a reference management application on which I rely cannot parse the results.

Is there any way to make Google Scholar use the previous page format?